# Accessing drawable file from String Arraylist in android

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm pretty new to Android development but I am trying to parse a local JSON file with JSON objects like this:

```
     "pigs": [
{
  "name": "Duroc",
  "list_image": "duroc_list",
  "desc_image": "duroc_desc",
  "description": "The Duroc pig is an older breed of domestic pig. The breed was developed in the United States and formed the basis for many mixed-breed commercial hogs. Duroc pigs are reddish-brown, large-framed, medium length, and muscular, with partially-drooping ears. They tend to be one of the least aggressive of all swine breeds raised for meat."
},
```

and I need to store the images into a RecyclerView specifically from "list_image" and the rest of the information is stored on separate activities when the image is clicked.

How would I go about getting the image to go into the RecyclerView when the image is stored in a local drawable folder?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!!!

EDIT:

After having the names of each image file stored in an array Ie: "duroc_list"

```
    ArrayList<String> list_image = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> desc_image = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> description = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        JSONArray pigArray = obj.getJSONArray("pigs");

        for (int i = 0; i < pigArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject pigDetail = pigArray.getJSONObject(i);

            name.add(pigDetail.getString("name"));
            list_image.add(pigDetail.getString("list_image"));
            desc_image.add(pigDetail.getString("desc_image"));
            description.add(pigDetail.getString("description"));

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How would each item in the array be selected and used in an adapter to be viewed in a RecyclerView?

Adapter:

```
   List<Integer> images;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public Adapter(Context context, List<Integer> images) {

    this.images = images;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.listPigs.setImageResource(images.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return images.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView listPigs;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        listPigs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get drawable from your drawable res folder by the saved name. For example if you have `ic_home.png` in your `res/drawable` folder you can get that passing `"ic_home"` as the first parameter of this method.

```
public static Drawable getDrawable(String name, Context context) {
    int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    return context.getResources().getDrawable(resourceId);
}
```

Comment: So the String "name" would be the name of the image file?

Comment: @Jordan Yes, that's it

Comment: What about calling this method? would it have to be done within an adapter?

Comment: For calling this method you need a Context. It can be an Application or Activity Context. You can pass that to Adapter, or even you can access the context from any View from your ViewHolder, by calling View.getContext().

Comment: Sweet thanks, I'll try it out!

Comment: Please vote for this answer or mark it answered if it would help you, thanks

Comment: Okay I will if it does

Comment: @Jordan please put your main activity code